# Alternative for isDisplayed() as it is not available in/from safari 12

Tags: java, selenium, macos-mojave, browserstack, safaridriver

In one of test steps before clicking some element I use selenium

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)
```

This method checks visibility by verifying that element is displayed

```
element.isDisplayed()
```

Tests are run on browserstack.

Note, that with combination OS X High Sierra + Safari 11 this step pass.
But with Mojave + Safari 12 after element is found and request
/session/:sessionId/element/:id/displayed is sent I see in selenium log responce "unknown command":

```
{"value":{"error":"unknown command","message":"The command 'GET \/session\/CD43B950-D8D6-49A4-A0FF-3F459F1F6D86\/element\/node-E721541C-713B-4607-8041-C79138E08704\/displayed' was not found.","stacktrace":""}}
```

Here I see that such request ("displayed") is missing:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/macos_webdriver_commands_for_safari_12_and_later?language=objc

So, the question: Is it possible use element.isDisplayed() with Safari 12? Am I miss something? If it's impossible, please share possible workarounds. Thanks

**Update**. From apple support:

> Please know that our engineering team has determined that this issue
>   behaves as intended based on the information provided.
>
> If you need element.isDisplayed(), we recommend that you copy the atom
>   into your repository and run it via Execute Script command. This is
>   what later versions of Selenium libraries have started doing, because
>   drivers do not necessarily ship it any more.

Clarification: In my tests selenium 2.52 is used

Comment: why can't you try Is Element Enabled if you wish to clickable instead of isDisplayed?

Comment: @DebanjanB looks this question mostly related to new version where isDisplayed is not available and duplicated question is something different. cross check once

Comment: @muraliselenium, thank you for alternative, I'll try it. And you right, the question is about safaridriver 12 mostly. I didn't find any information how to use isDisplayed with Safari 12.